# python create variables from dictionary entries

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, namespaces

I would love to do something like this:

```
rates={'r1':10, 'r2':20}
```

and then do some cool command (what is it???) to end up with variables in my namespace

```
>>>r1 
10

>>>r2
20
```

Is this a dumb idea?

Comment: You are generally better sticking with the dictionary than trying to play with dynamic variables

Comment: Defining a dictionary and injecting it into the globals namespace is actually _more typing_ than just doing `r1=10;r2=20` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
globals().update(rates)
```

Anyway, it's usually a bad practice.

[globals()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#globals)

Comment: This won't work (unless `locals()` is `globals()`). Well, in some implementations of Python it might work, but at least in CPython it won't.

Comment: @WolframH: You're right, edited with globals(), that should be fine.