# How do I return locals() and then re-define them in another function?

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following;

```
def a():
    a = ...
    b = ...
    ...
    n = ...

    return locals()

def b(**kwargs):
    """Some function that would assign all keys and values in this function"""
   print(a)
   print(d)

if __name__=="__main__":
    b(**a())
```

I have a long list of variables and I would like to do the above instead of doing

```
def a():
    a = ...
    b = ...
    ...
    n = ...

    return a,b,c,d,e ... n

def b(a,b,c,d,e ... n):
   print(a)
   print(d)

if __name__=="__main__":
    a,b,c,d,e ... n = a()
    b(a,b,c,d,e,f ... n)
```

I've tried fiddling around with `exec` and `locals().update(dict)` but these haven't worked for me.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `kwargs['a']` in `b`?

Comment: `b` is already written. I would have to go through and change every variable in `b` to `kwargs['n']`. This could work, but doesn't seem like the best way to accomplish this goal. I would rather just add something to `b`'s signature or the first few lines of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python create variables from dictionary entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675221/python-create-variables-from-dictionary-entries)

Comment: `exec` will only help you in Py2

Comment: @DYZ this solution works, which is nice. However, I've read several pages including the one you linked that updating globals is a bad practice. I do want the functions only accessible in `b` and not in different function.

Comment: Just replace `globals()` with `locals()`. I thought it was kind of obvious.

Comment: Right. I've tried that before and I get a `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: In addition, I wouldn't have to `return locals()`, in `a`, I could just do `globals().update(locals())`. I could then just run `b()` sans arguments and it would work. However, I don't want these variables to be global. Just defined in `a` and used in `b` and other functions I may choose to write.

Comment: updating `locals()` might not always work: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/370f7a956cef5895c93ca5a53fc26b04df973aaf/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1493

Comment: Also, it needs to be mentioned that [the preference of explicit over implicit code in Python aims to help readability and comprehensibility](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#explicit-code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Python 3, the `exec` statement is no longer available as a way to create an actual local dictionary within a function. This means that there is no longer a way to create local variables within a function without explicitly naming them. If you wish to use a large number of unnamed arguments, you may want to reference them from `kwargs` as dictionary items. While your comment indicates that rewriting `b` as

```
def b(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['a'])
    print(kwargs['d'])
```

may be a lot of up-front work, it is probably going to be worth it in the end. Even with `@das-g`'s excellent answer, you will still have to explicitly write all the names you want to use.

If `b` is the last stopping point for your `kwargs` dictionary, you should consider using [@das-g's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490508/2988730) and list the arguments you need explicitly. This improves clarity and makes documentation and annotation a little easier.

If you intend to pass `kwargs` around to other functions from `b`, listing the arguments out would effectively remove them from `kwargs`, so you should probably use the approach I have described above.

Comment: Indeed. As contradictory as that might sound: If the function is too large to be rewritten, then it is too large. And should thus be rewritten.

Comment: @das-g. I think you just found a contradictory way to phrase a pretty sound principle :)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
def a():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = 5
    return locals()

def b(*, a, d, **kwargs):  # explicitly declare key word arguments you care about
    print(a)
    print(d)

b(**a())
# Prints
# 1
# 4
```

Keyword arguments declared explicitly in the function signature will be available under local variables of the respective names within the function, instead of as entries of `kwargs`. `**kwargs` is still required so that the function can accept the rest of the dictionary entries as further keyword arguments (that it'll happily ignore if `kwargs` isn't used within the function).

The `*,` in front of the explicit keyword arguments keeps them from being used as positional arguments. If you don't want that restriction, leave out the `*,`

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: One of the goals would be to eliminate the need to explicitly declare each argument I care about in the signature of `b`

Comment: @p014k. Why? If you are using all the arguments, why not have them listed. If nothing else, it makes things more explicit. Also, it allows you to document the inputs better.